# Black Jack Game Probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I am reviewing for my upcoming test but I have difficulty in solving one problem because the way the define the variable **X** causing my confusion.I really need your help to build up a good solution for this problem.

> Jack plays a game which assigns a number that is uniformly distributed
> between 0 and 5. If the game assigns a number less than or equal to
> **k** then he loses 1 dollar. On the other hand, if the game assigns a number larger than **k**, then he will gain 1 dollar.
>
> (a) Find the expected profit of the game.
>
> (b) What is the **k** value, which minimizes the variance of the
> profit obtained in this game?
>
> (c) If you were to play this game 10 times, what is the probability
> that you gain 2 dollars?

Actually, I have thought that I will put **X** as the number of numbers which is less than or equal to **k**. Due to uniform distribution, I think I can build up a Probability distribution Function (PDF) can be expressed

```
        1/6, if X in [0, k]

F(X) =  5/6, if X in (k, 5]

          0, otherwise.
```

For this case, I can put **Y** according to X which shows the profit of Jack playing this game. However, I think the way I solve is wrong due to the expression of **X**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote profit by $\pi$. Then

(a) $E[\pi] = (-1)\cdot P(\pi=-1)+(+1)\cdot P(\pi=1) = (-1)\cdot \frac{k}{5}+(+1)\cdot \frac{5-k}{5} = \frac{5-2k}{5}$

(b)$Var[\pi] = E[\pi^2] - \left(\frac{5-2k}{5}\right)^2 = \frac{k}{5} + \frac{5-k}{5} - \frac{(5-2k)^2}{25} = 1 - \frac{(5-2k)^2}{25} \to \min$

Solution is $k^* = 0$ or $k^* = 5$ (both yield $Var[\pi] = 0$)

(c) It is possible only if we have exactly 6 successes. Hence $$P(6 \text{ successes } ) = \binom{10}{6}\left(1-\frac{k}{5}\right)^6\left(\frac{k}{5}\right)^4$$

Comment: Can you add some more details for this answer?

Comment: @HoangNam Is it more clear now? If not, could you please specify which details you need?

Comment: What does the variable pi stand for? I do not understand the meaning of this variable?

Comment: @HoangNam It is profit, and $E[\pi]$ means expected profit, what we wanna find in (a)...